# How to create a slide out animated hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

This is my code,
index.html:-

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Cool Navbar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="pc-nav">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Saroni Global</h1>

            <div class="menu">
                <a href="" class="is-active">Home</a>
                <a href="">About</a>
                <a href="">Products</a>
                <a href="">Contact</a>
            </div>

            <button class="hamburger">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav class="mobile-nav">
        <a href="">Home</a>
        <a href="">About</a>
        <a href="">Products</a>
        <a href="">Contact</a>
    </nav>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.sass code:-

```
$primary: #8c38ff
$light: #eeeeee
$dark: #212121

* 
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
    box-sizing: border-box
    font-family: 'Fira sans', sans-serif

.container
    max-width: 1280px
    margin: 0 auto
    
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    justify-content: space-between

header
    position: fixed
    left: 0
    right: 0
    z-index: 99    
    background-color: $dark
    padding: 16px 32px
    border-bottom: 3px solid $primary

h1
    color: #FFF
    font-size: 26px
    font-weight: 900
    letter-spacing: 1px
    text-transform: uppercase

.hamburger
    display: block
    position: relative
    z-index: 1

    user-select: none

    appearance: none
    border: none
    outline: none
    background: none
    cursor: pointer
    span
        display: block
        width: 33px
        height: 4px
        margin-bottom: 5px
        position: 
        
        background-color: $light
        border-radius: 6px
        z-index: 1

        transform-origin: 0 0

        transition: 0.4s
    

.hamburger:hover
    span:nth-child(2)
        transform: translateX(10px)
        background-color: $primary
.is-active
    span:nth-child(1)
        transform: translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg)
    span:nth-child(2)
        opacity: 0
        transform: translateX(15px)
    span:nth-child(3)
        transform: translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg)
.is-active:hover
    span
        background-color: $primary

.menu
    display: none
    flex: 1 1 0%
    justify-content: flex-end
    margin: 0 -16px
    a
        color: #FFF
        margin: 0 16px
        font-weight: 600
        text-decoration: none
        transition: 0.4s
        padding: 8px 16px
        border-radius: 19px
    a
    .is-active
        background-color: $primary
    a:hover
        background-color: $primary



@media (min-width: 768px) 
    .hamburger
        display: none
    .menu
        display: flex
```

My javascript doesn't contain much it just adds an class to my hamburger menu icon to animate the when clicked, but I wanted to know how to create an animated hamburger slider. How can I do it, btw for whom who doesn't know sass is it's just a sassy version of css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Fira sans', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #8c38ff;
}

h1 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.hamburger {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  user-select: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburger span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.hamburger:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  background-color: #8c38ff;
}

.is-active span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0px, -2px) rotate(45deg);
}

.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(15px);
}

.is-active span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translate(-3px, 3px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.is-active:hover span {
  background-color: #8c38ff;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 0 -16px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 19px;
}

.menu .is-active {
  background-color: #8c38ff;
}

.menu a:hover {
  background-color: #8c38ff;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .hamburger {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="pc-nav">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Saroni Global</h1>

    <div class="menu">
      <a href="" class="is-active">Home</a>
      <a href="">About</a>
      <a href="">Products</a>
      <a href="">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <button class="hamburger">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</header>
<nav class="mobile-nav">
  <a href="">Home</a>
  <a href="">About</a>
  <a href="">Products</a>
  <a href="">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Added Compiled Sass because majority of developers (myself included) can read CSS  easier.

Comment: <https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/hamburger-menu-css/> easy to implement animated hamburger icons